# mongodb - query based on _id timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I write a mongodb shell query that will return the documents (or just document ids) for all objects created after a specific date?  I see examples like the following...

[return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)

But they just return the timestamp, I want to query based on a timestamp.  I don't think the logic is as easy as looking for objects higher than a specific objectid, because if mongodb is sharded, then there are multiple servers creating objects.

Comment: I believe this might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It makes sense now, I take the hex value of the epoch time, and add "0000000000000000", that will give me the base objectid to start at.  Thanks,

Comment: To find all objects created after 2013-01-21, this would be the query...   db.User.find({'_id': {'$gte' : ObjectId('50FCCB500000000000000000')}})