# Mongoose query within the same schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to perform a query within the same schema?
For example, If I have a schema which has 2 date fields, and I need to find the data where one Date field is greater than the other.
This is my schema and code sample.

```js
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var someSchema = new Schema({
   someId          :  { type: String, default: '' ,index:true, unique: true  },
   userName   :  { type: String, default: ''},
   fullName   :  { type: String, default: '' },
   created      :   {type: Date, default:''},
   lastUpdated     :   {type: Date, default:''},
   primaryGroupId  :   {type:String,default:''},
   nextHearing     :   {type: Date, default:''},
   status   :  {type:String,default:'open'},
   
});



mongoose.model('Problem', someSchema);
```

The below code is my query.

```js
var problemModel = mongoose.model('Problem');

var today = Date.now();

problemModel.find({$and:[{'nextHearing':{$lte: today}},{'nextHearing':{$gte : 'lastUpdated'}}]},function(err, result){
```

When I run the program, I get the following error

**{ message: 'Cast to date failed for value "lastUpdated" at path "nextHearing"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'date',
  value: 'lastUpdated',
  path: 'nextHearing' }**

Answer (score 0):

> new Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in UTC.

so you may need to change:

```
var today = Date.now();
```

to

```
var today = new Date().toISOString();
```

Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.
I tried using your code as well.  The error is with this `{'nextHearing':{$gte : 'lastUpdated'}}`

Comment: both `nextHearing` and `lastUpdated` are fields of the same schema, is it possible to compare them the way I have done? If not, what's the possible solution?