# ISO8601 Date Strings in MongoDB (Indexing and Querying)

Tags: mongodb, date

I've got a collection of documents in MongoDB that all have a "date" field, which is an ISO8601 formatted date string (i.e. created by the moment.js format() method).

I'd like to be able to efficiently run queries against this collection that expresses the sentiment "documents that have a date that is after A and before B" (i.e. documents within a range of dates).

Should I be storing my dates as something other than ISO-8601 strings? Contingent upon that answer, what would the MongoDB query operation look like for my aforementioned requirement? I'm envisioning something like:

```
{$and: [
  {date: {$gt: "2017-05-02T03:15:22-04:00"}},
  {date: {$lt: "2017-06-02T03:15:22-04:00"}},
]}
```

Does that "just work"? I need some convincing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely want to use the built-in [date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) data type with an index on your `date` field and **not** strings. String comparison is going to be slow as hell compared to comparing dates which are just 64bit integers.

As far as querying is concerned, check out the answer here:

[return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)