# how to write a find query with condition for date with M/D/YYYY format and stored as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two fields in my collection like below

```
{
    "StartDate" : "1/2/2019",
    "EndDate" : "5/14/2019"
}
```

i want to write a find query to get the documents with in current date
example `db.collection.find({StartDate:{$lte: '5/9/2019'},EndDate:{$gte:'5/10/2019'}})`

but here **'5/14/2019' >= '5/9/2019'** this condition is returning false
**'5/14/2019' >= '5/9/2019'** this is returning true

I don't understand why it is happening I cannot use **MM/DD/YY** format I have to stick to **M/D/YYYY** format

please provide me with a better solution thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)

Comment: Are `"StartDate"` and `"EndDate"` stored as [ISODate](https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/) objects or as simple strings? In the first case, this question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: both are strings

Comment: The only way to reliably compare dates formatted as strings is if they are formatted as `YYYY/MM/DD`, anything else won't be consistent. You'll probably have to parse the dates first before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, both dates are simple strings. In order to use logical operators on them, you have to first convert them to ISODate objects by using the [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) pipeline like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
        "StartDateISO": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "$StartDate",
                "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
            },
        },
        "EndDateISO": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "$EndDate",
                "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
            }
        },
        "queryStartDateISO": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "5/9/2019",
                "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
            }
        },
        "queryEndDateISO": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "5/10/2019",
                "format": "%m/%d/%Y"
            }
        },
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$expr": {
            "$and": [
                {"$lte": ["$StartDateISO", "$queryStartDateISO"]},
                {"$gte": ["$EndDateISO", "$queryEndDateISO"]}
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

It will work in **MongoDB 4.0** and newer. The dates were parsed correctly in my tests:

`"StartDate": "1/3/2019"` became `"StartDateISO": "2019-01-03 00:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: The string dates in the database are parsed correctly because I specified their format. There's still a problem with `new Date("5/10/2019")}` - it's not always consistent. Do you also need to stick to the m/d/Y format in the search query? If so, I'll try to come up with a solution to parse these dates as well.

Comment: I updated the code - now all dates are parsed (both in the query and in the database)

Comment: my mongo version server is below 4.0