# Query mongodb to get documents created within last 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

I'm in Central European Summer Time (CEST) at 15:08 I added document to my collection. In model to `new Schema` I'm passing `timestamps: true`. Its createdAt is incorrect, it's two hours too early:

```
createdAt:2019-08-21 13:08:39.219
```

Why? Also what does `.219` at the end mean? Lastly how can I query this collection to get every one which createdAt is within last 30 minutes?

```
const c = await Collection.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date() // ???
    }
});
```

I've combined answers with comments and tried something like this:

```
const d = new Date(
    new Date().getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 - 30 * 60000
);
const c = await Collection.find({
    createdAt: { $gte: d }
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I execute this code at 15:47 CEST which is 13:47 UTC so earliest document should be from 13:17 but I get results with `"createdAt": "2019-08-21T12:43:38.395Z",`.

Comment: two hours too early..UTC time?

Comment: That, and milliseconds.

Comment: MongoDB stores times in UTC, which is 2 hours behind your timezone. It's up to your application to convert from UTC to localtime if needed when displaying to a user.

Comment: Okey thanks, and what about query?

Comment: @dopeCode, `var d=new Date(); d.setMinutes(-30)` and pass `$gte: d`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/mongodb-return-query-based-on-date) I have an answer there that use `$dateSubtract` and does not involves client side timezone processing. You can just put specific timezone info with `timezone` option for `$dateSubtract`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date that ignores your browser timezone:

```
function newDateTZSafe(){
    var now = new Date();
    return new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
}
```

or as alternative, if you heavily rely on dates, use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this query**
const c = await Collection.find({
    createdAt: {
        "$gte" : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 30) }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use this query  to get last 30 minutes record from db