# Filter Data between two String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have a creation date attribute of a document which has a format like this: "05/03/2020" of type String.

I must extract all the documents from my system having a creation date before "05/03/2020".

I tried with:

```
db.MyCollection.find ({DateC: {$lte: "05/03/2020"}})
```

but it still returns 0.

Is there a way to compare if a date format String is before another date?

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest you to find out which format you must use to query your DB. Then, you map your input format to your DB format. `05/03/2020` is very unlikely to be ready to be usable in a query. To perform date format, you can use moment.js, which is a pretty good lib to handle dates.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835850/5860648 I think it is a good example of how to query based on a date. Then, if your input is not in the proper format, format it the way you need :)

Comment: yes, but i have more than 3000 document with this format "01/12/2020" so i can't update them all.

Comment: the problem is that the format in my system is String not a date so the example is not helping me

Comment: Storing a date as a string is not a good practice, exactly because you won't be able to use date comparison operators further. If I were you, I would first probably plan a migration to fix your data in the DB first. Otherwise, you will have to fetch the whole DB in memory to perform the check programmatically, which you don't want. Plan a migration and fix your DB data to use it properly afterwards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator to convert `$DateC` to ISODate,

- Make sure your input should be in ISODate format,

```
db.MyCollection.find([
  {
    $expr: {
      $lte: [
        {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$DateC",
            format: "%d/%m/%Y"
          }
        },
        ISODate("2020-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w-2UOEkI58H)

> I am not sure with your date format, I have predicted as `d/m/y`, you can manage it your self if its different.