# How to compare two dates with Mongodb (find query using NestJS)

Tags: mongodb, request, find

I'm trying to get the list of posts for which the publish date is equal or less than the current date.

I'm using NestJS, Mongo & typeORM; which syntax should I use?

```js
const posts =
  await this.mbRepository.find(
    { where: { "deletedAt": null , "publishDate" <= currentDate } }
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    let firstPoint = new Date();
    firstPoint.setHours(0);
    firstPoint.setMinutes(0);
    firstPoint.setSeconds(0);
    let lastPoint = new Date();
    lastPoint.setHours(23);
    lastPoint.setMinutes(59);
    lastPoint.setSeconds(59);

    const posts = await this.mbRepository.find({ publishDate: { $gte: firstPoint, $lt: lastPoint } } });
```

Get current day and make two point. One as begining of the day and another as end of the day. Then you can use mongodb operator `$gte` and `$lt`. In this way you will get all post which have been publish in this time range.