# mongodb aggregate query not working on dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

i am trying to fetch data from mongodb using aggregate query in nodejs for a specific date range,

```
    let date = '20230925'
    let year = date.slice(0, 4);
    let month = String(date.slice(4, 6)).padStart(2, '0');
    let day = date.slice(6, 8);
    let startFormatedDate:any = `${year}-${month}-${day}T00:01:01.111+00:00`
    let endFormatedDate:any = `${year}-${month}-${day}T23:58:58.998+00:00`
```

My aggregate query is

```
{ $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
{
  $match: { $and: [ 
    { updatedAt: { $gt: startFormatedDate } },
    { updatedAt: { $lt: endFormatedDate } }
   ], },
},
```

with this condition i am getting data for 2023-09-25, but i am also getting data for 2023-09-26

can anyone suggest me what might be the issue

**EDIT :**

```
{
  $match: { $and: [ 
   { updatedAt: { $gt: new Date(startFormatedDate) } },
   { updatedAt: { $lt: new Date(endFormatedDate) } },
  ],},
},
{ $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
```

with updated query, i am getting same result.

Comment: Can you try converting the input string to date type by `$gt: new Date(startFormatedDate)` and also for `$lt` condition.

Comment: Out of the question, to avoid sorting in the whole collection and to use the index you should put `$sort` stage after `$match` stage.

Comment: @turivishal i updated the question & tried with new Date(), but i am getting same result.

Comment: What is the datatype of field `updatedAt` in collection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return query based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835757/return-query-based-on-date)

Comment: @turivishal in schema i have defined it as '{ timestamps: true }'

Comment: You need to show example document, with the datatype you have in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 3rd party Date library, e.g. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon). Then it would be simply:

```
let date = '20230925'

  {
    $match: {
      updatedAt: {
        $gte: DateTime.fromISO(date).toJSDate(),
        $lte: DateTime.fromISO(date).endOf('day').toJSDate()
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from MongoDB using an aggregate query in Node.js for a specific date range, you can use the $match operator in combination with $gte (greater than or equal) and $lte (less than or equal) operators. Example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let date = '20230925'
let year = date.slice(0, 4);
let month = String(date.slice(4, 6)).padStart(2, '0');
let day = date.slice(6, 8);
let startFormatedDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T00:01:01.111+00:00`);
let endFormatedDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T23:58:58.998+00:00`);

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err, client) {
  if(err) throw err;

  const db = client.db('your_database_name');
  const collection = db.collection('your_collection_name');

  collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        date_field: {
          $gte: startFormatedDate,
          $lte: endFormatedDate
        }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
  });
});
```